# Elasticsearch-PHP needs curl or custom http handler

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

i'm deploy laravel 5.2 to ubuntu and installed elasticquent lib and elasticsearch 2.3.4 , when i try to figure the result of aggregation :

```
RuntimeException in ClientBuilder.php line 144:
Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler.
```

I already install curl using command sudo apt-get install php5-curl and its still display the same error

How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: maybe too late but check allow_url_fopen in your php.ini. I got similar error GuzzleHttp requires cURL, the allow_url_fopen ini setting, or a custom HTTP handler.. allow_url_fopen = On fixes issue

Answer (score 25):

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

Try this, it will install curl as per your version of php.

Comment: I had to `sudo service apache2 restart` after installing php curl to get it to work

Answer (score 5):

You must run  `sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl` to install curl and its php extension,  if  you are using PHP7, you must install `php7.0-curl` instead of `php5-curl`

Comment: nice, but Jaydeeps solution is better.